# Ruby DataMapper::ImmutableError

Tags: ruby, datamapper

```
get '/watch/:id' do |id|
    @results = Twitchtvst.all( :fields => [:Twitchtv ],
                 :conditions => { :user_id => "#{id}" }           
               )  
    #p @results.inspect
    @results.each do |result|
      puts result.id
    end

    erb :mystream
  end
```

I get this error message immutable resource cannot be lazy loaded. How do I fix this?

**The Error message is:**

```
DataMapper::ImmutableError at /watch/1
Immutable resource cannot be lazy loaded
```

Comment: What error message???

Comment: immutable resource cannot be lazy loaded

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html):

> Note that if you don't include the primary key in the selected columns, you will not be able to modify the returned resources because DataMapper cannot know how to persist them. DataMapper will raise DataMapper::ImmutableError if you're trying to do so nevertheless.

I know that you are not modifying anything here but I think that the same rule applies for lazy loading. So I will suggest to try it like that:

```
@results = Twitchtvst.all( :fields => [:Twitchtv, :id],
             :conditions => { :user_id => "#{id}" }           
           )  ode here
```

Note the id as an additional field.